# WPF; override background & foreground color of SELECTED TEXT in a textbox/combobox

Tags: wpf

in WPF c# is it possible to set a global resource to override ALL textbox/combobox COLORS for highlighted text (the default is a gray background [not the color of the drop down list in the combobox]). I don't know how to set it locally either, this seems like it should be simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

In app.xaml
If you want all then remove the x:Key
This is ListViewItem but I think it will work for ComboBoxItem

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemNoColor" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create a control template for TextBox and apply it to all textboxes by TargetType.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
    <!--.
    .
    . Set some props here
    .-->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!--Edit your control template here. (you can change everything here like selected text highlights and etc)-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```